# NHIbernate: Difference between Restriction.In and Restriction.InG

Tags: c#, nhibernate, orm

When creating a criteria in NHibernate I can use

Restriction.In() or
Restriction.InG()

What is the difference between them?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

InG is the generic equivalent of In (for collections)

The signatures of the methods are as follows (only the ICollection In overload is shown):

```
In(string propertyName, ICollection values)
```

vs.

```
InG<T>(string propertyName, ICollection<T> values)
```

Looking at NHibernate's source code (trunk) it seems that they both copy the collection to an object array and use that going forward, so I don't think there is a performance difference between them.

I personally just use the In one most of the time - its easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

Restriction.In definately creates a subquery with whatever criteria you pass to the .In() method, but not sure what InG() does. never seen it.